# Django: cache unless output has changed?

Tags: django, caching

This is a newbie question from someone who doesn't know much about HTTP caching :)

I'm using Django with the @never_cache decorator.

Is there a way I can instruct the browser to cache the page *unless* the content has changed, in which case the browser should reload the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree with Dominic and there is a very good reason to generate the page, see if it's changed and throw it away if it hasn't - and that's to avoid the need to transfer the entire page over the internet. This only makes sense if your page is quite cheap to generate and is fairly large, but it can be a quick win.

The mechanism for doing this is the [ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) header. Django has good support for this, just set [USE_ETAGS](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-USE_ETAGS) in settings.py and you'll get the benefit of returning 304 Not Modified responses where appropriate on all your pages.

Comment: Yes, my page is just like that, so thanks! I'll use the ETag header.

Comment: excellent point - failed to account for the use case the OP was after.

Answer (score 3):

I think reading this would be a good starting point:

https://web.archive.org/web/20180101014856/http://eflorenzano.com/blog/2008/11/29/drop-dead-simple-django-caching/

An excerpt:

> Caching is easy to screw up. Usually it's a manual process which is error-prone and tedious. It's actually quite easy to cache, but knowing when to **invalidate which caches becomes a lot harder**. [...] The underlying idea is that every Django model has a primary key, which makes for an excellent key to a cache. Using this basic idea, we can cover a fairly large use case for caching, automatically, in a much more deterministic way.